# Issue transferring values from one array to a new one

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

I am trying to create a program which would fill up an array that is initialized at 2 elemental values, but lets the user keep on entering numbers. As the user enters more values, the program is supposed to create a new array with 2 more element holders, transfer the numbers from the initial array to the new one, and delete the old one.

Once the user inputs *-1*, the program is supposed to do other stuff with the array, which I know how to do, but since the input is not stopping when I enter *-1*, I just didn't bother with that part yet.

To be honest though, I have no idea what I am doing here since I am new to the concepts of *new* and *delete*. I do have some code, but only because I was given hints.

If it was up to me, I probably would have tried to do this with vectors.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *ptr;   //pointer to array
    int capacity = 2;   //capactity of array
    int size = 0;       //how many ints recorded in array
    ptr = new int[capacity];
    int tmp = 0;

    int *numArray = new int[capacity];

    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        while (true) {
            cout << "Enter a number: ";
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            if (num == -1) break;
            if (size == capacity) {
                int *temp = new int[capacity + 2];
                capacity += 2;
                delete[] ptr;
                *ptr = tmp;
            }
            ptr[size == capacity] = num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never increment `size`.  There is no point having an infinite for-loop containing an infinite while-loop, then calling `break` from that inner loop, only to loop around again.  `ptr[size == capacity]` is only ever going to write to `ptr[0]` or `ptr[1]`.  `*ptr = tmp` should at least generate a compiler warning if not error.  This program would be about 2 lines long and actually work if you used `vector`.

Comment: @paddy As much as I would have loved to use vectors, the specifications for this program don't grant me that leisure. Although I suppose I could write it with vectors for now, and change it if need be. The point on me doing it like this was to help me develop the skills for _new_ and _delete_

Comment: Your use of `break` is only breaking out of the while(true) loop. The for loop will never end, either. There's really no sense in the outer loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  But there are several issues.

1. ditch the `for` loop.  Otherwise when you `break` from the `while` loop, it just enters again forever.
2. You need to increment `size`, otherwise `size == capacity` will never be true.
3. You forgot to actually copy the values in when resizing the array.
4. Incorrect assignment `*ptr = temp` should be `ptr = temp`.
5. Bogus array assignment using boolean index `ptr[size == capacity] = num`.  Perhaps combine this with **(2)** and do `ptr[size++] = num`.

All this together:

```
while (true)
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    if (num == -1) break;
    if (size == capacity){
        int *temp = new int[capacity + 2];
        for( int i = 0; i < capacity; i++ ) temp[i] = ptr[i];
        capacity += 2;
        delete[]ptr;
        ptr = tmp;
    }
    ptr[size++] = num;
}
```

Comment: The reason why I had it as _*ptr_  is because otherwise I get this error for it: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'

Comment: @MehMoose "fixing" compiler errors by putting stars somewhere until the error goes away,  is not a good idea.  You will most likely just turn the error into a different type of error that happens at runtime instead. In this case the fix was to insert an `e` between the `m` and the `p`.  (consider using more meaningful variable names...)

Comment: While this works for what my initial problem was (that it didn't stop when I entered _-1_,  when I implement coding I have to find the lowest value in the array, it acts weird  For instance, it tells me that the lowest value is  -842150451, and when it identifies the elements, it gives the same value ( -842150451) to them.

Comment: Then I suggest you post a different question about it, since there is no code at all in your question for finding the lowest value.  I guarantee that you forgot to initialise the "lowest" before looping.

Answer (score 0):

First, would recommend you using char array. You can use memcpy for this. Below code assume you read one int at a time.

```
int *temp = new int[capacity + 2];
memcpy ( tmp, ptr, capacity );
temp[capacity + 1] = num;
capacity += 2;
```